# Bluetooth connection from Mac to Pi disconnects a few seconds after successful connection

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I'm having an issue with my MacBook Pro (2013) where if I try to pair it with my Raspberry Pi 3 using Bluetooth, it connects after confirming the code it displays, then after about 5-10 seconds, it disconnects. I'm using bluetoothctl to make the connection.

bluesman logs this (about 5-10 seconds after the connection succeeds):

```
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                           [hci0] 142.006498
        Handle: 11
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                [hci0] 142.007119
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                           [hci0] 142.132796
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 11
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ Device Disconnected: B8:E8:56:3D:7C:BD (0) reason 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actively use the Bluetooth connection? If you are not using it after pairing, then there is no need to keep it connected. Try to start a serial connection and you should see that the connection is reestablished automatically.